# Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

when I try to compile project:Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

this is my build.gradle(Module: app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.chistaapplication.www.myapplication20"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        dependencies {
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to mark something as a duplicate, please put a link in your comment to the original question.  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace compile with implementation like this

```
dependencies {
            implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        }
```